# Average formula results while skipping errors

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to average the results of the ratios of three sets of sumifs formulas referencing three different years data on three separate sheets. i.e. I want my formula to be average(formula 1, formula 2, formula 3). The problem is for part of my data set formula 1 or formula 3 might throw an error because there's only data of that type on one or two of the years. So I want to exclude those averages only the years that have data. Solutions I've found online to this problem such as average(if(iserror don't work because I'm not averaging an array. I tried this and it returns #VALUE! and I can't for the life of me figure out why:

> =AVERAGE(IFERROR((SUMIFS('2014 Data'!$T:$T,'2014 Data'!$F:$F,'Az    Diamondbacks'!$D$1,'2014 Data'!$V:$V,'Az Diamondbacks'!J$3,'2014 Data'!$L:$L,'Az Diamondbacks'!$B4)/SUMIFS('2014 Data'!$T:$T,'2014 >Data'!$F:$F,'Az Diamondbacks'!$D$1,'2014 Data'!$V:$V,'Az Diamondbacks'!J$3)),""),IFERROR((SUMIFS('2015 Data'!$T:$T,'2015 Data'!$F:$F,'Az Diamondbacks'!$D$1,'2015 Data'!$V:$V,'Az Diamondbacks'!J$3,'2015 Data'!$L:$L,'Az Diamondbacks'!$B4)/SUMIFS('2015 Data'!$T:$T,'2015 >Data'!$F:$F,'Az Diamondbacks'!$D$1,'2015 Data'!$V:$V,'Az Diamondbacks'!J$3)),""),IFERROR((SUMIFS('2016 Data'!$T:$T,'2016 Data'!$F:$F,'Az Diamondbacks'!$D$1,'2016 Data'!$V:$V,'Az Diamondbacks'!J$3,'2016 Data'!$L:$L,'Az Diamondbacks'!$B4)/SUMIFS('2016 Data'!$T:$T,'2016 Data'!$F:$F,'Az Diamondbacks'!$D$1,'2016 Data'!$V:$V,'Az Diamondbacks'!J$3)),""))

Comment: Would be a lot easier in VBA, are you willing to go that route?

Answer (score 2):

When you put the values directly in to `AVERAGE` function then the "null string" "" returned by `IFERROR` forces an error.

Try using `CHOOSE` function to supply an array to the `AVERAGE` function, e.g.

`=AVERAGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},IFERROR(SUMIF1,""),IFERROR(SUMIF2,""),IFERROR(SUMIF3,"")))`

replace `SUMIF1`, `SUMIF2` and `SUMIF3` with your three formulas or cell references containing those formulas

Comment: a good explanation of a method that can be applied to many situations, well done. I think I can use this - solving some issues...